# C# getting a string[] from byte[]

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have a array byte[]. It contains the lines of a string[], seperated with line breaks. What would the best way to get the string[] back from the byte[]? Encoding is utf-8.

```
byte[] lines[];

string[] str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(lines).Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Would be an option, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: The only time I needed that, I used something like this, which looks even worse: `using (var ms = new MemoryStream(lines)) { using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8)) { string line; while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) { // ... } } }`. Very curious to find an easier way.

Comment: 'best' is subjective. Does 'best' mean 'easiest to read the code' or 'most efficient' or 'uses least memory'? The answer will depend on what you want in that regard.

Comment: @SimonRobinson - Yes, OP didn't specify. I'd be interested in the "most efficient", meaning "fastest" way.

Comment: @SimonRobinson best for most efficent.

Comment: OK in that case I'd stick with the method you've got for now, unless you *know* the performance is unsatisfactory. If you need something faster, try going through the byte array manually as per my comment in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that solution you provided in quiestion **is** the best way.
I don't know any other methods of getting string from byte array (knowing the encoding) or splitting string into array.

Comment: Theoretically, one other way would be to iterate through the byte array, looking at each element and using StringBuilders to build the strings as you go.  I imagine that would use less memory as you're not using an intermediate string that has the entire text, but the code would be a lot more complex, so I doubt I would ever do that in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on your source of `string[]`, you could potentially use `BinaryFormatter` and then `Serialize` your `string[]` to a `byte[]` first off and then `Deserialize` back to a `string[]` later on; however this means that you will need the `string[]` first off so it sort of defeats the object...

The code you have mentioned is probably the best way, if I am perfectly honest and as other have suggested - you can read each byte with a `StringBuilder` but that is probably even messier.

Here is the link to [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)